# What is an academic profile?

Tags: masters, research-undergraduate

I am filling out an application & research profile form for a Masters program. The form consists of four open-ended questions, with plenty of space to fill out information for each.

One question is 'Research Experience and Interests: Comment on why you would like to pursue graduate studies, with a clear identified objective. Further clarify if you have a particular research interest, possibly in the context of
past experience and accomplishments'.

A third question is 'Academic Profile: Describe your academic profile, highlighting particular achievements and relevant scholarships or awards'

My question is: I have worked on a research project which spanned over the course of a year. I would like to describe this project, but I am not sure which section to fit this information in. It initially seemed obvious to fit in the first question (research experience), but wouldn't research (especially considering it's my only major research opportunity) also fit under 'academic profile'? I want to avoid overlap to my answer for both of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Academic profile seems to have two meanings. An academic profile in the overall field and discipline is the "status" or respectability of the academic in the universe of academics in the area as implied in this [other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71169/how-to-boost-academic-profile-for-masters-application). However, that definition of academic profile is not relevant in your current application.

Your masters application refers to your academic interest as explained by your past achievements and awards, conference attendance etc. It is more of [a narrative and evolution of your work and study history](https://patthomson.net/2014/10/13/what-is-an-academic-profile/). Your academic profile allows you to include all the evidence to support your interests and passions. Even school related and work related awards and experience that is relevant only adds to the development of your interest. I have seen how people incorporate their activism and volunteering roles into their profile with good effect for example.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Then, according to my understanding of your answer, I should describe my research project under the research experience question, and possibly elaborate it (with a link to a relevant page) under my academic profile?